# fetch data error php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch data from mysql and display it in the page but I couldn't,here is my code`

```html
 $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = '';
   
    
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
   
   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
    
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
    mysql_select_db('pharmacynew');

    
    $result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    
    ?>
        <tr> 
          <td><?php echo $row['productID']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['ProductName']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['Quantity']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['Price']; ?></td>
         
          <td><?php
     
   ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['RegisterDate']; ?></td>
         
     <td><a href="Clientedit.php?cid=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>"><strong>Edit</strong></a> | <a href="Clientdel.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>"><strong>Delete</strong></a> | <a href="Clientcomplaintlist.php?cid=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>"><strong>Complaints</strong></a></td>
        </tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

the error is saying  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Phramacy\showitems.php on line 71
which is this line "`if ($result->num_rows > 0) {"`
can any one provide help on that,thanks so much

Comment: You are using old mysql  you should really be using mysqli or PDO because the old mysql adapter is deprecated since version 5.5.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**$result->num_rows** can be used only with mysqli. Try using, **if (mysql_num_rows($result))**. 
Also you have missed the **mysql_fetch_array/mysql_fetch_assoc** part too.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';


$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
mysql_select_db('pharmacynew');


$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    ?>
        <tr> 
          <td><?php echo $row['productID']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['ProductName']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['Quantity']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['Price']; ?></td>

          <td><?php

   ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['RegisterDate']; ?></td>

     <td><a href="Clientedit.php?cid=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>"><strong>Edit</strong></a> | <a href="Clientdel.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>"><strong>Delete</strong></a> | <a href="Clientcomplaintlist.php?cid=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>"><strong>Complaints</strong></a></td>
        </tr>
  <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

With the old mysql adapter you need to use `if (mysql_num_rows($result))` but you should really be using mysqli or PDO because the old mysql adapter is deprecated.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

> Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Use`mysqli_* or PDO`

`note :` your mixing mysql with mysqli

```
    //db connection

 global $conn;

    $servername = "localhost";  //host name

    $username = "username"; //username

    $password = "password"; //password

    $mysql_database = "dbname"; //database name

//mysqli prepared statement 

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

    mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
    $stmt->execute();
    $get_result =$stmt->get_result();

    $row_count= $get_result->num_rows;

if ($row_count > 0) 
{

  while($row=$get_result->fetch_assoc())
  {

?>
        <tr> 
          <td><?php echo $row['productID']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['ProductName']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['Quantity']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['Price']; ?></td>

          <td><?php echo $row['any_column_name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['RegisterDate']; ?></td>

     <td><a href="Clientedit.php?cid=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>"><strong>Edit</strong></a> | <a href="Clientdel.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>"><strong>Delete</strong></a> | <a href="Clientcomplaintlist.php?cid=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>"><strong>Complaints</strong></a></td>
        </tr>
  <?php
  }

  }
  ?>
```